# How to Start Cron / Crond inside the Official Postgres Container

Tags: postgresql, docker, cron, daemon

The `crond` is not running by default in the [official `postgres` alpine image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/). How could I define my `Dockerfile` to make sure that the daemon runs in the background? I want that it is running by default, if possible even when the container gets restarted.

I tried to add `CMD ["/usr/sbin/crond"]` to my `Dockerfile` but I didn't succeed. Any thoughts how to run this in combination with `postgres`?

**Update**

*I have added the answer of [tianon](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/353):*

> [...]
>   If you must run crond inside a container, I'd recommend instead using
>   a separate container which runs nothing but crond (and thus Docker can
>   both track its lifecycle, and restart it when/if it fails, the machine
>   restarts, etc). You should be able to connect to the PostgreSQL
>   instance from a second container, but if absolutely necessary, one
>   could use things like --network container:some-postgres in order to
>   join the network namespace of the database container directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pg_cron` must be added to `shared_preload_libraries`. Per the docs:

```
 # add to postgresql.conf:
 shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_cron'
```

and you must then *restart* PostgreSQL.